# Why C++ optimizer show different behavior for static method and static function?

Tags: c++, optimization

I wrap uint8_t with a class and many constexpr methods and constructors.
I have to write a custom memset for my class, but the C++ optimizer doesn't optimize it correctly when it becomes a member of the class.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

class CType {};

template<typename T, typename SuperType>
class CPrimitiveType : public CType {
protected:
public:
    using RawType = T;
    T fRaw;

    constexpr CPrimitiveType() = default;
    constexpr CPrimitiveType(RawType value) : fRaw(value) {}
    constexpr CPrimitiveType(const CPrimitiveType<T, SuperType> &value) : fRaw(value.fRaw) {}
    constexpr RawType operator()() const { return fRaw; }

    constexpr inline SuperType &operator=(const SuperType value) {
        this->fRaw = value.fRaw;
        return *this;
    }
};

class U8 : public CPrimitiveType<uint8_t, U8> {
public:
    using CPrimitiveType::CPrimitiveType;
};

template<typename T>
struct SSetMemory {};

template<>
struct SSetMemory<U8 *> {
    [[gnu::noinline]] static void SetMemory(U8 *src, U8 value, size_t size) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            *src++ = value;
        }
    }
};

[[gnu::noinline]]
static void SetMemory(U8 *src, U8 value, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        *src++ = value;
    }
}

int main() {
    U8 *arr = new U8[4096];
    memset(arr, 0, 4096);
    printf("%d", arr[0].fRaw);
    SSetMemory<U8 *>::SetMemory(arr, 1, 4096);
    printf("%d", arr[0].fRaw);
    SetMemory(arr, 2, 4096);
    printf("%d", arr[0].fRaw);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Msnbjsd63

In above code "SetMemory" function correctly optimize to memset but SSetMemory<U8 *>::SetMemory doesn't optimze to memset.
What is the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: `U8 *arr;` directly followed by a lot of dereferencing of the ***uninitialized*** pointer `arr`? What do you hope to accomplish by that?

Comment: As above plus turn warnings on - live - https://godbolt.org/z/eb73Yzo8M

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: I add U8 *arr; to prevent optimizer from removing unused codes.

Comment: @MohsenTi but with UB the compiler is allow to do anything, especially the optimizer can, for example, remove all code on a UB path through the program as UB can not occur in a conforming program.  Testing code with UB invalidates all testing, code-gen etc.  One of my favourites [Old New Thing - Undefined Behaviour can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you for your advice, It's seems implicit copy constructor cause this behave but why ?

Comment: The variable `arr` is *uninitialized*. It will contain an *indeterminate* value (that you should really look at as garbage). Any attempt to use indeterminate values lead to *undefined behavior*. To solve your problem you need to actually initialize `arr` to point somewhere valid, like `U8* arr = new U8[4096]` (or simply `U8 arr[4096];`). There's nothing directly wrong with any of your classes or functions (that I can see at a quick glance), but you just can't keep dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Fix UB in code https://godbolt.org/z/Msnbjsd63 but result is same. I can't see UB in code any more.

Comment: @MohsenTi Note that it changed how `SetMemory` is compiled. The function is marked `static` and therefore can only be used in the translation unit where it is defined. Even though you marked it `noinline` the compiler is optimizing based on the knowledge that it is only called with specific arguments. It is optimizing it specifically for a size of `4096` for example. On the other hand the member function has external linkage, so the compiler cannot make any assumptions that it is not called with other arguments in another translation unit.

Comment: Also, `memset` on a non-trivially-copyable type also causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @user17732522 Your are right.because of static flag on SetMemory, optimizer show different behave and optimize code for specific size.

Comment: @MohsenTi -- *I can't see UB in code any more* -- The code is fundamentally broken due to the usage of `memset`.  [See the compiler warning](https://godbolt.org/z/hfKaYrd3d).  One thing to remember -- if you are not aware of what to look for, then of course the code will look ok to you.  It requires another person or persons with experience to spot these errors that you are not aware of, and is a huge reason why code reviews are done in the industry.

Comment: I think in this specific case it is a missed optimization that the compiler doesn't compile it to a `memset`. In general there is the issue that due to how C++ copy elision rules and the ABI specifications work it is possible that `src` points to `value` in a call if `U8` is non-trivially-copyable, which seems to be what prevents the optimization. Using `__restrict` on `src` or `int` instead of `U8` for `value` does optimize to `memset`. However, in this specific case, even if `src` points to `value`, there is no problem with calling `memset`, the only legal value of `size` would be `0`/`1`.